# Asynchronous process inside parent function - return async process result?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a piece of code that has an asynchronous function inside another function. I need to wait for that asynchronous function to finish before the return statement is executed in the parent function. I am new to promises and despite my extensive reading on stackoverflow, I just can't get the order right, thus my return statement of the parent function is executed before the asynchronous process is done. The asynchronous process should return a string and then I would like to return that string from the parent function. I'm hoping someone can help me structure this.

```
//Call the parent function
mgmtTractPopupBox.setContent(mgmtPopupContent);

function mgmtPopupContent(feature) {
    //set up query
    //Need this query to complete before executing "return content;" below
    //"relatedQuery" returns a deferred object, once that resolves, 
    //it enters the callback function.
    var content = queryableMgmtTractFL.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery, relatedQueryComplete).then(function(value) {
        //This prints the result value of the relatedQuery promise (an Object), 
        //which is not what I need. I need the HTML string created in the
        //the relatedQueryComplete function.
        console.log(value);
    });
    //This executes before the asynchronous process has finished
    return content;
}

function relatedQueryComplete(relatedRecords) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        var content = '<table id="mgmtPopupTable1"><tr><th>Veg Mgmt Practice</th><th>Herbicide</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>\
            <th>Implemented By</th><th>Funded By</th><th>Farm Bill Code</th></tr>';
        //do stuff that adds to content variable
        content = content + '</table>';
        resolve(content);
    });
}
```

I understand that `relatedQueryComplete` should return a promise, and inside that promise I should be able to access a value, which I believe would be the `content` that I resolved the promise with. My `.then()` does not return the promise value of `relatedQueryComplete` though, and instead returns the resolved value of `relatedQuery`. I have attempted to structure the promises like this, but haven't had success:

```
var content = queryableMgmtTractFL.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery).then(relatedQueryComplete).then(function(value){...}
```

Obviously, my understanding on promises is messed up. Can someone help me structure this correctly? Additionally - I really need to pass an extra parameter to my callback function `relatedQueryComplete` but `...(relatedQuery, relatedQueryComplete(extraParam))...` doesn't do the job. I know I would need some sort of wrapper like

```
callback(function(resultFromRelatedQuery){
   relatedQueryComplete(resultFromRelatedQuery, extraParam)
});
```

but the `resultFromRelatedQuery` would end up being the `relatedQuery` deferred object and not the resolved value. So confused right now.

Comment: That `console.log(value);` in the `then` callback should definitely work. Are you showing us your actual code?

Comment: What is `relatedQueryComplete` really doing? There's nothing asynchronous in your code.

Comment: If `mgmtTractPopupBox.setContent(…)` does not support asynchronous functionality in its callback, you've simply lost. There's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recently added `async/await` functionality. Say you have `firstAsyncFunction` and `secondAsyncFunction`.

```
async function secondAsyncFunction(param1, param2) {
    const result1 = await firstAsyncFunction();
    // do stuffs with result1, get a new result
    return resultFromSecondAsyncFunction;
}
```

Then you can use that this way:

```
secondAsyncFunction(param1, param2).then((resultFromSecondAsyncFunction) => {
    // do stuffs with resultFromSecondAsyncFunction...
});
```

`await` is the keyword that will make javascript "wait" until it gets the result from the other async function to execute what comes after.

You can check out [javascript.info/async-await](https://javascript.info/async-await) out for more on `async/await`.

Comment: If I could trouble you some, would you mind showing me the structure with the exact function names I have? I'm not understanding how you would define async functions in a format of `queryableMgmtTractFL.queryRelatedFeatures(...)`. I can't change that format given the platform I have to do this on. `relatedQuery` is required to be there. `queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery)` acts on `relatedQuery` automatically, it's a built in method of the program this JS is intergrated with.